# [ERROR] []: Action client not connected, Moveit to Gazebo

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello again friends,

This is almost an exact replica as question [319411](https://answers.ros.org/question/319411/rviz-moveit-issue-with-controller-action-client-not-connected/), but as there is no answer there, I have included more information in an attempt to solve the issue.

The error is received when attempting to run the file `t800_planning_execution.launch` as seen below:

```
 <launch>

  <rosparam command ="load" file="$(find t800_moveit_config)/config/joint_names.yaml"/>

  <include file="$(find t800_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch">
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true"/>
  </include>

  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="use_gui" value="false"/>
    <rosparam param="source_list">[/joint_states]</rosparam>
  </node>
<!-- Launch moveit -->
    <include file="$(find t800_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
        <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" default="true"/>
    </include>

    <!-- Run Rviz and load the default config to see the state of the move_group node -->
    <include file="$(find t800_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
      <arg name="config" value="true"/>
    </include>

</launch>
```

When `t800_planning_execution.launch` is run, and before the system is settled, the `rostopic list` results can be seen below:

```
/attached_collision_object
/collision_object
/head_mount_kinect/depth_registered/points
/joint_states
/move_group/cancel
/move_group/display_contacts
/move_group/display_planned_path
/move_group/feedback
/move_group/filtered_cloud
/move_group/goal
/move_group/monitored_planning_scene
/move_group/ompl/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/ompl/parameter_updates
/move_group/planning_scene_monitor/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/planning_scene_monitor/parameter_updates
/move_group/result
/move_group/status
/planning_scene
/planning_scene_world
/recognized_object_array
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/feedback
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/update
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/update_full
/rviz_ubuntu_19788_1914554999/motionplanning_planning_scene_monitor/parameter_descriptions
/rviz_ubuntu_19788_1914554999/motionplanning_planning_scene_monitor/parameter_updates
/t800_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/cancel
/t800_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/feedback
/t800_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
/t800_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/result
/t800_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/status
/tf
/tf_static
/trajectory_execution_event
```

And after:

```
/attached_collision_object
/collision_object
/execute_trajectory/cancel
/execute_trajectory/feedback
/execute_trajectory/goal
/execute_trajectory/result
/execute_trajectory/status
/head_mount_kinect/depth_registered/points
/joint_states
/move_group/cancel
/move_group/display_contacts
/move_group/display_planned_path
/move_group/feedback
/move_group/filtered_cloud
/move_group/goal
/move_group/monitored_planning_scene
/move_group/ompl/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/ompl/parameter_updates
/move_group/plan_execution/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/plan_execution/parameter_updates
/move_group/planning_scene_monitor/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/planning_scene_monitor/parameter_updates
/move_group/result
/move_group/sense_for_plan/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/sense_for_plan/parameter_updates
/move_group/status
/move_group/trajectory_execution/parameter_descriptions
/move_group/trajectory_execution/parameter_updates
/pickup/cancel
/pickup/feedback
/pickup/goal
/pickup/result
/pickup/status
/place/cancel
/place/feedback
/place/goal
/place/result
/place/status
/planning_scene
/planning_scene_world
/recognized_object_array
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/feedback
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/update
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/update_full
/rviz_ubuntu_19788_1914554999/motionplanning_planning_scene_monitor/parameter_descriptions
/rviz_ubuntu_19788_1914554999/motionplanning_planning_scene_monitor/parameter_updates
/tf
/tf_static
/trajectory_execution_event
```

Unfortunately I am still a pleb, so I cannot take a picture of my rqt_graph, but it is only a `/joint_state_publisher` node sending `/joint_states` to a `/move_group` node, and to itself.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352048/%5Berror%5D-%5B%5D:-action-client-not-connected,-moveit-to-gazebo/) by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2020-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-05-12**:
Could you please post the actual error message and the content of your moveit_config package's `ros_controllers.yaml`? Do the controller names that gazebo offers match the names in that file?

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-13**:
The actual error message was the same (verbatim) as question #[319411](https://answers.ros.org/question/319411/rviz-moveit-issue-with-controller-action-client-not-connected/):

```
[ERROR] [1553337582.435615335]: Action client not connected: arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
[ INFO] [1553337582.443550146]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1553337582.460904199]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
```

and

```
[ERROR] [1553338700.303182035]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ elbow_joint shoulder_lift_joint shoulder_pan_joint wrist_1_joint wrist_2_joint wrist_3_joint ]
[ERROR] [1553338700.303209126]: Known controllers and their joints:

[ERROR] [1553338700.303249995]: Apparently trajectory initialization failed
```

I ended up using another method however.

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-13**:
This indeed was an issue of matching the controller names in the file to those expected in gazebo! @fvd

My git for the project can be found [here](https://github.com/matthewmarkey44/arm/tree/master/src/arm_moveit_config).

The files that I created:

controllers.yaml
controllers1.yaml

The files I modified:
demo_gazebo.launch
gazebo.launch
ros_controllers.launch
arm_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml

When demo_gazebo.launch is run, both rviz and gazebo open successfully and I am able to send the moveit instructions to the gazebo model.

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-13**:
The only issue now is that I have not successfully fixed my base_link to the gazebo world and am now struggling with that. Thank you for the response @fvd

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-05-13**:
I'm glad you could solve it. Could you post this as an answer and accept it, so it is out of the queue? Thanks!

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-13**:
Ya, sorry about that I wasn't sure if that was an ok thing to do.  Thanks again for the guidance...if you have a second and you know of a quick fix...[352213](https://answers.ros.org/question/352213/gazebo-model-not-fixed-to-world-virtualdummy-joints/)...if not thanks for taking a look anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This indeed was an issue of matching the controller names in the file to those expected in gazebo! @fvd
My git for the project can be found [here](https://github.com/matthewmarkey44/arm/tree/master/src/arm_moveit_config).

The files that I created:
controllers.yaml
controllers1.yaml

The files I modified:
demo_gazebo.launch
gazebo.launch ros_controllers.launch arm_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml

When demo_gazebo.launch is run, both rviz and gazebo open successfully and I am able to send the moveit instructions to the gazebo model.

---

Originally posted by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) with karma: 68 on 2020-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0